# Go: Marshal empty struct into json

Tags: go

I'm trying to marshal a struct into json. It works when the struct has values. However, I'm unable to access the webpage when the struct has no value:

Go:

```
type Fruits struct {
    Apple []*Description 'json:"apple, omitempty"'
}

type Description struct {
    Color string
    Weight int
}

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    j := {[]}
    js, _ := json.Marshal(j)
    w.Write(js)
}
```

Is the error because json.Marshal cannot marshal an empty struct?

Comment: What error? You're explicitly ignoring the error. It might help to check it. Also, {[]} is invalid syntax in Go.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://play.golang.org/p/k6d6y7TnIQ

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Fruits struct {
    Apple []*Description `json:"apple, omitempty"`
}

type Description struct {
    Color string
    Weight int
}

func main() {
    j := Fruits{[]*Description{}} // This is the syntax for creating an empty Fruits
    // OR: var j Fruits
    js, err := json.Marshal(j)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(js))
}
```